# Responsive Design Select All

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been working on making my website responsive so other people on different devices can view it. I saw this code on W3schools to update the sizes and positions of my elements. `[class*="col-"]` I was wondering if you could change the col- to like * all or something? The reason I say this is because I want to select all my elements to edit them for phones.

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? Please edit the original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your website responsive for phones, you should take a look at CSS media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries

They offer the functionality for some specific styling to kick in, if the width of the device used to access your website matches X amount of pixels.